# Непорядок с нервной системой

Tags: грамотная-речь

Какими прилагательными выразить непорядок с нервной системой?

Нездоровая, воспаленная, слабая н. с., какие еще варианты?

Comment: А в чём именно "непорядок"? Какой диагноз Вы имеете в виду? (Или хотя бы симптоматику укажите.)

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, наиболее надёжный вариант "расшатанная нервная система".
Или просто "расшатанные нервы".

Иногда ещё говорят "неустойчивая нервная система".

Answer (score 1):

Термин есть  - лабильная.

> Лаби́льность (от лат. labilis «скользящий, неустойчивый») в физиологии
>   — функциональная подвижность, скорость протекания элементарных циклов
>   возбуждения в нервной и мышечной тканях.

[Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x)

> **ЛАБИЛЬНЫЙ**, -ая, -ое. [лат. labilis] *Спец.* Нестойкий, неустойчивый, подвижный. *Л-ое давление. Л-ая температура.*

**[Лабильность нервной системы](http://nashinervy.ru/o-nervnoj-sisteme/emotsionalnaya-labilnost-nervnoj-sistemy.html)**

> Люди неоднократно сталкивались с таким термином, как лабильная нервная
>   система, но далеко не каждый знает, что он означает. Это патология
>   нервной системы, при которой наблюдается непостоянство в поведении,
>   частые перепады настроения, резкий всплеск эмоций, который могут
>   спровоцировать самые обычные вещи. При постановке данного диагноза
>   специалисты в первую очередь должны учесть возрастную группу пациента,
>   его темперамент и особенности характера.